# Property encapsulation inserting code automatically, but I don't want it there?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm making a public property, and it keeps inserting a snippet of code.  What is this code for?  And how come it doesn't happen to my other public properties?

Specifically the snippet:

```
Set(value As ObjectName())
```

Here's the full public property code:

```
Public Property PropertyName() As ObjectName()
            Get
                Return Me.propertyName
            End Get
            Set(value As ObjectName())
                Me.propertyName = value
            End Set
        End Property
```

When I try deleting

```
(value As ObjectName())
```

It keeps coming back.  But my other properties, that snippet of code doesn't automatically generate...

Comment: I added the visual studio tag if you do not mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a property, you need a get and set (unless it is readonly).

The `get` part is for when other code tries to access the value of the property.  The `set` part is for when other code tries to write the value of the property.  The (`value As ObjectName())` part is simply the definition of parameter expected.

It will generate for your other properties too, if you were to start typing to define them.  Visual Studio is decent at leaving existing code alone.  If you already have a property definition, it won't add it.

Again, if you have a `ReadOnly` property, there will be no `set` method.

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't asking what the public property is used for lol.  I'm just asking specifically about that snippet of code... "(value as ObjectName())"

Comment: @Fritos, see my last edit.  That part of the property definition defines a parameter for set, so you can use it in your code.  If you were to go back and redefine your existing properties, VS would indeed insert that part into them.

Comment: cool thanks!  Is this a new feature of VS2010?  Was the syntax different before?  I'm working on older code, and it doesn't have that snippet.

Comment: @Fritos, I'm not sure if it is new or not, but VS definite completes a lot of code for you.  I believe there was a default way of accessing the value on set without it being completely defined, but I don't remember what it was, sorry.  If your code compiles, there is no problem with your old code.  Both syntaxes probably work just fine still.